# gem pg not installing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

So I had to reinitialize a project after my pc crashed and am in the process of reinstalling all my gems on ruby.  Unfortunately when I run bundle install I get the following error.

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing pg:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

current directory: /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0/ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.3 -r ./siteconf20170925-462-dsymf.rb extconf.rb
mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/include/ruby.h

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0 
for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/pg-
0.21.0/gem_make.out
```

If someone could give me a point in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Install this package from terminal. `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`.

Comment: Make sure you have the Ruby development files installed, if you are on a rhel-based system you can `yum install ruby-devel`. A better option would be to use something like rbenv or rvm to manage your ruby installations.

Comment: Thanks guys it worked my bundle is good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
 sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list"
 wget --quiet -O - http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install postgresql-common
 sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.5 libpq-dev
```

gem install pg

Recommend with ruby 2.4.2

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql
sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
```